# Sql use function/procedure from another db using current db context

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-visualization

I'm working on an application which use several databases corresponding to several customers (this choice is a company choice, there are some some resons to work with this architecture). All these db are made with the same structure, tables and views and use identical functions/procedures to carry out their treatment.

My problem is that this architecture is difficult to maintain because of the redundancies and I am currently looking to group all the identical functions in the same place.
So I tried to create another database in which to put my functions and procedures but the problem is that I don't know how to use the context of the database on which I want to work and not the one where the functions are stored.

I tried to use the DBNAME() function but it return the "business logic" db name and not the data db name.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: You'll need to create the `FUNCTION`s in each of the databases; you can't pass database context to a user defined function nor can they dynamic run against a specific database. This is one draw back of the method you are using; many databases, many places to deploy. This is why your change management needs to be very well streamlined instead.

Comment: Would there be a way to modify the different "instances" of a function in a centralized way ? for example "Alter function Base1.foo, Base2.foo, Base3.foo as begin ... end" ?

Comment: No, if you have 100 databases, and each have a function that needs `ALTER`ed, then you need to run 100 `ALTER` statements. If you don't have any, then I suggest you invest in some change management and change automation software.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

First create your function into the master DB, then make it a system object, last use it with its complete name.

Demo :

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_DBNAME()
RETURNS sysname
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN DB_NAME()
END;
GO

EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject 'F_DBNAME';
GO

USE tempdb;
GO

SELECT master.dbo.F_DBNAME()
GO
```

Comment: in your example, this function will return "master". Is there a way for the function to return the context ? in your example, it would return "tempdb"